# Recargar la pagina luego de descargar un archivo usando jquery en .netcore 6

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Con la siguiente sentencia en jquery hago una petición Ajax a una acción JsonResult, esta genera un archivo en una dirección previamente conocida por mí y luego me devuelve el nombre del archivo generado, luego de esto redirecciono la página hacia otra acción que me devuelve un FileResult.

Deseo que luego de dar la opción de guardar el archivo y este sea guardado donde el usuario desee tomándose su tiempo, luego refrescar la página, no me gustaría solo usar un **setTimeout** ya que no se el tiempo que durara el usuario guardando el archivo ni si lo guardo en sí.

Deseo recargar la pagina una vez el archivo ya haya sido descargado.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Generate_TXT_File", "ControllerName")',
    type: "GET",
    data: { parameter1: value1, parameter2: value2, parameter3: value3 },
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.filename != '')// file was generated
        {           
            window.location.href = "@Url.RouteUrl(new { Controller = "ControllerName", Action = "Download" })/?file=" + result.filename;
        }
        else if (result.status === 'error')
        {
            console.log(result.Message);
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
    }
});
```